# Good ways to host or distribute my patch for the Linux Kernel Mailing List

Tags: linux-kernel, development, patch

I have an approximately 1500 line patch for the Linux kernel - introducing a new file system.

I have lots of problems with posting a patch straight to the kernel mailing list (gmail mangles the patch/it's very long/no easily apparent way to break the patch up except by hand etc)

I don't want to use git format-patch as it generates a long, long series of patches, many of which are junk (eg debug printks and the like) and I am not at present able to suggest people pull off my git (I'm on the road and it's on a lap top without a fixed IP and so on).

So, what is the best way to do this? I fear this is too large to host at github (is it?) or is there an easy way to get people to be able to pull the patch for testing in a way that will be acceptable to people on LKML?

Comment: It isn't too large to host at github

Comment: There are currently 638 forks of [torvalds / linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) at GitHub.  I'm pretty sure they could handle 639.

Comment: Yes, I now realise that GitHub will do this - last time I tried, about 8 - 10 months ago, the kernel was too big, now they are hosting it.

Answer (score 5):

The process is clearly defined in the kernel source code.

```
system1:/usr/src/linux/Documentation # ll SubmittingPatches 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28473 Dec  2  2009 SubmittingPatches
```

They go over every step you have to take. It looks like email is the only way. I would recommend getting another free account or simply mail it from your laptop using `nail | mail` and modify the `return address` to be your Gmail account.